# Django create field in ModelForm if condition is True

Tags: django, django-forms

I am going to have a Product, which can have some variations, and also Product, which has no variants. So for the first case, there should be fields 'quantity' and 'variant' select box rendered. For the second case, only a field with 'quantity' should be rendered because the product has no variants.

Is possible to do that somehow with ModelForms?

This is my form, where now quantity and variant is mandatory to fill:

```python
    class AddToCartForm(forms.ModelForm):
        variant = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=ProductVariant.objects.none(),
        )
        quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=1)
    
        class Meta:
            model = OrderItem
            fields = ['quantity', 'variant']
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.product_id = kwargs.pop('product_id')
            product = Product.objects.get(id=self.product_id)
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
            self.fields['variant'].queryset = product.variant.all()
    
        def clean(self):
            product_id = self.product_id
            product = Product.objects.get(id=self.product_id)
            quantity = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
            if product.stock < quantity:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    f'The maximum stock available is {product.stock}')
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would advice to make two `ModelForm`s for that. One with the variants and one without. You can implement common logic in one, and then inherit in the other to minimize code duplication.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but then I need to create a separate view for ProductDetail page, right? I am using 
```generic.FormView
``` for my ProductDetail view. I am not sure if CBV supports more than one form for a single view.

Comment: you can override `get_form_class` and return thus one of the two depending on the conditions.